# Cannot apply first and last child CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors

I created navigation menu, but cannot solve problem with first and last element in the menu. So i apply for elements :first-child and :last-child. But it does not work.

```
<div id="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Four</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Five</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Six</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And CSS file

```
#navigation li{
font-family: 'PT Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 18px;
list-style: none;
display: inline-block;
line-height: 60px;
}

#navigation li a {
color: #fff; 
text-decoration: none;
font-weight: bold;
}

#navigation li a:first-child {
color: #f0f0f0;
}

#navigation li a:last-of-type {
color: #000;
}
```

For example i created - http://jsfiddle.net/t48Qm/

Answer (score 3):

That's because all the `a` elements are the *only* children, and therefore are both the `:first-child` *and* the `:last-child` of their parent `li` elements. To target the `a` of the first, and last, `li`:

```
li:first-child a {
    /* CSS here */
}

li:last-child a {
    /* CSS here */
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/t48Qm/1/).

Comment: We aim to please! And you are, of course, more than welcome; I'm glad to have been of help. =)